# Bring up toad intellisense

Tags: sql, intellisense, toad

When typing a query in Toad it usually brings up an intellisense scrolling box to help with my typing.

But sometimes this does not appear. Is there a short cut (like in Visual Studio) to bring it up?

**EDIT** I found that the key mapping is CTRL+.

For a query like

```
SELECT * FROM Person AS P
WHERE P. -- I expect intellisense to show me the columns. 
         -- Sometimes it does not and pressing the CTRL+. does nothing
```

Pressing CTRL+. away from a query brings up a very long list of things like -

> @@CONNECTIONS @@CPU_BUSY @@CURSOR_ROWS  @@DATEFIRST  @@DBTS  @@ERROR

Do I have the correct shortcut key?

Is the problem that Toad can't figure out the column names in the query above?

**EDIT 2**

Very strange behavior

If I have

```
USE DB1
SELECT * FROM Person AS P
WHERE P.--I get the intellisense
```

BUT if I have the following in the editor -

```
USE DB1
SELECT * FROM Person AS P
WHERE P.--I get the intellisense

USE DB2 
SELECT * FROM Company AS C
WHERE C. -- No intellisense
```

**Solution below in my own answer**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems if there is a second USE on the page intellisense will not work with queries below the second USE!

If I have

```
USE DB1
SELECT * FROM Person AS P
WHERE P.--I get the intellisense
```

BUT if I have the following in the editor -

```
USE DB1
SELECT * FROM Person AS P
WHERE P.--I get the intellisense

USE DB2 
SELECT * FROM Company AS C
WHERE C. -- No intellisense
```

It seems if there is a second USE on the page intellisense will not work with queries below the second USE!

Answer (score 11):

I suggest you to use `CTRL+T` combination. I used it and it works. Also [Dell official support](https://support.quest.com/SolutionDetail.aspx?id=SOL47923) agrees, [here](https://support.quest.com/SolutionDetail.aspx?id=SOL6776) too. Toad is not the greatest software for best user experience :)

Comment: On my install it looks like it is mapped to CTRL+.

Comment: yep, there's two mappings, just like the support pages suggest.

Comment: Ctrl+T and Ctrl+. both work, but note that they don't work in all cases like they would in regular programming languages. It depends on the text before the Intellisense.

Answer (score 1):

CTRL-TAB will bring it up for you.

hope this helps!

Comment: see here for a whole list of handy shortcuts: http://www.mandsconsulting.com/toad-sql-editor-useful-shortcuts

Comment: On my Toad CTRL-TAB changes the active windown, like in a browser.

Answer (score -1):

You have to complete first query to get intellisense in second one.
So if you complete first query i.e.

```
USE DB1
SELECT * FROM Person AS P
WHERE P.FirstName = ‘Sanket’
```

Then only you can get intellisense in second query.

```
USE DB2 
SELECT * FROM Company AS C
WHERE C. --Get the intellisense
```